# connecting the nodes with relationships in py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I have the following python code to make a graph in neo4j. I am using py2neo version 2.0.3.

```
 import json
    from py2neo import neo4j, Node, Relationship, Graph

    graph = neo4j.Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
       with open("example.json") as f:
        for line in f:
            while True:
                try:
                    file = json.loads(line)
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    # Not yet a complete JSON value
                    line += next(f)

                    # Now creating the node and relationships

            news, = graph.create(Node("Mainstream_News", id=unicode(file["_id"]), entry_url=unicode(file["entry_url"]),
                                      title=unicode(file["title"])))  # Comma unpacks length-1 tuple.
            authors, = graph.create(
                Node("Authors", auth_name=unicode(file["auth_name"]), auth_url=unicode(file["auth_url"]),
                     auth_eml=unicode(file["auth_eml"])))

            graph.create(Relationship(news, "hasAuthor", authors ))
```

I can create a graph with nodes Mainstream_News and Authors with a relation 'hasAuthor'. My problem is when I am doing this I am having one Mainstream_News node with one Authors but in reality one author nodes has more than one Mainstream_News. I would like to make `auth_name` property of a Author nodes as a index to connect with the Mainstream_news nodes. Any suggestions will be great.

Answer (score 4):

You are creating a new `Authors` node each time through your loop, even if an Author node (with the same properties) already exists.

First, I think you should create uniqueness constraints on `Authors(auth_name)` and `Mainstream_News(id)`, to enforce what seem to be your requirements. This only needs to be done *once*. A uniqueness constraint also creates an index for you automatically, which is a bonus.

```
graph.schema.create_uniqueness_constraint("Authors", "auth_name")
graph.schema.create_uniqueness_constraint("Mainstream_News", "id")
```

But you will probably have to empty out your DB first (at least of all `Authors` and `Mainstream_News` nodes and their relationships), since I presume it currently has a lot of duplicate nodes.

Then, you can use the `merge_one` and `create_unique` APIs to prevent duplicate nodes and relationships:

```
news = graph.merge_one("Mainstream_News", "id", unicode(file["_id"]))
news.properties["entry_url"] = unicode(file["entry_url"])
news.properties["title"] = unicode(file["title"])

authors = graph.merge_one("Authors", "auth_name", unicode(file["auth_name"]))
news.properties["auth_url"] = unicode(file["auth_url"])
news.properties["auth_eml"] = unicode(file["auth_eml"])

graph.create_unique(Relationship(news, "hasAuthor", authors))
```

Comment: Very great pointing to the unique constraint implementation but still getting weird error while using merge_one : TypeError: merge_one() takes at most 4 arguments (8 given)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I normally do, as I find it easier to know what's happening. As far as I know there are a but when you create_unique with only a Node, and there are no need to create the nodes, when you also have to create an edge.

I don't have the database on this computer, so please bear with me, if there are some typo'es, I'll correct it in the morning, but I guess you'll rather have a fast answer.. :-)

```
news = graph.cypher.execute_one('MATCH (m:Mainstream_News) '
    'WHERE m.id = {id} '
    'RETURN p'.format(id=unicode(file["_id"])))

if not news:
   news = Node("Mainstream_News")
   news.properties['id] = unicode(file["_id"])
   news.properties['entry_url'] = unicode(file["entry_url"])
   news.properties['title'] = unicode(file["title"])

# You can make a for-loop here
authors = Node("Authors")
authors.properties['auth_name'] = unicode(file["auth_name"])
authors.properties['auth_url'] = unicode(file["auth_url"])
authors.properties['auth_eml'] = unicode(file["auth_eml"])

rel = Relationship(new, "hasAuthor", authors)
graph.create_unique(rel)
# For-loop should end here
```

I've included the tree first lines, to make it more generic. It returns a node-object or None.

---

**EDIT**:

@cybersam use of schema is cool, implement that to, I'll try to use it myselfe also.. :-)

You can read more about it here:
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-constraints.html
http://py2neo.org/2.0/schema.html